# Update Query to match string to column Name

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I have the following UI on my program

[image]

Then I have a table with the following columns

[image]

What I want to do is to write a query that looks at the "Item" string on my combo box and then updates the above column, in this case Handbooks, of the table above where the Generalist name matches the column. The record should be updated every time, in other words, I want to replace the information every time.

I have no idea where to begin on this. This the query I used to create the table I want to update.

```
    SELECT repName.Rep_Name, repName.Handbooks, repName.Leaves
FROM     repName INNER JOIN
                  Positions ON repName.Job_Code = Positions.Job_Code
ORDER BY repName.Rep_Name
```

In case this helps somewhat

Comment: Why did you put data of the "item" dropdown as fixed fields in your table?. Are you sure you are designing well your data model?. Maybe if you have a table for "items" it would be simplier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess is, as I put on the comment above, that your design is not well.

Nonetheless if in your scenario you still need to do what you are asking, then you could use dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(1000)
DECLARE @column varchar(50)

SET @column = 'foo' 
SET @value = 'bar'

SET @sqlCommand = 'UPDATE TABLE SET ' + @column + ' = ' + @value 
EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```

You could pass the value with parameters or whatever approach is better to your case.